# How to stop repetition in a for-loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have some files that should be read. Based on their length, I have to choose some indices using a for-loop. The problem is that in every cycle of for-loop, it adds the past list to the next list which is incorrect. How can I stop this repetition and have one separated list in each cycle. The code that I have written is below:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Function to find middle index
def find_midd(input_list): #middleIndex %2 != 0:
    middleIndex = int(float(len(input_list))) /2
    if middleIndex %2 == 0:
        return middleIndex 
    else:
        return middleIndex - 0.5



file1= np.arange(0,1197)
file2= np.arange(0,1000)
file3= np.arange(0,1204)
file4= np.arange(0,1303)
file5= np.arange(0,1100)
file6= np.arange(0,1420)
file7= np.arange(0,999)

l = [f for f in sorted(os.listdir('.')) if f.startswith('file')]
for i, d in enumerate(l): 
  df = pd.read_csv(d,sep="\s+",header=None)
  e = df.iloc[:,5]
  c = df.iloc[:,4]
  
  df1 = pd.DataFrame()
  middleIndex = find_midd(e)
  middleIndex = int(middleIndex)
  lis = [5,10,12, 15 , 17]
  for i in lis:
   ans = middleIndex+15*i


   NEW_middle_index.append(ans)
  print(NEW_middle_index)
```

The current wrong output is:

```
[641, 716, 746, 791, 821]
[641, 716, 746, 791, 821, 682, 757, 787, 832, 862]
[641, 716, 746, 791, 821, 682, 757, 787, 832, 862, 598, 673, 703, 748, 778]
[641, 716, 746, 791, 821, 682, 757, 787, 832, 862, 598, 673, 703, 748, 778, 675, 750, 780, 825, 855]
[641, 716, 746, 791, 821, 682, 757, 787, 832, 862, 598, 673, 703, 748, 778, 675, 750, 780, 825, 855, 707, 782, 812, 857, 887]
[641, 716, 746, 791, 821, 682, 757, 787, 832, 862, 598, 673, 703, 748, 778, 675, 750, 780, 825, 855, 707, 782, 812, 857, 887, 693, 768, 798, 843, 873]
```

The expected result:

```
[641, 716, 746, 791, 821]
[682, 757, 787, 832, 862]
[598, 673, 703, 748, 778]
[675, 750, 780, 825, 855]
[707, 782, 812, 857, 887]
[693, 768, 798, 843, 873]
```

Comment: You are appending to the same variable `NEW_middle_index`. You can use a different variable for every iteration or make your list empty after every assignment.

Comment: @William I got your point and solution. Is it possible to answer my question by myself? I don't want to be banned by the community because of asking a question that remains unanswered.

Comment: You can update your question with your findings for future reference for other people.

Comment: Where exactly do you declare the `NEW_middle_index` list?

Comment: @MichaelSidoroff `NEW_middle_index` is a list of integer indices that changes from a variable to another variable.

Comment: @Michael I have found my answer but I am banned to ask any questions, could you please upvote in order to release my ban?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code you are appending to the same variable NEW_middle_index. To solve this issue you can use a different variable for every iteration.